# Update query in post SQL property in informatica power center

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Source table and target table is a same table.
I have created mapping to apply some logics and connected it to target table. If I write update query in post SQL will it update the source table correctly.. ?

Answer (score 0):

The query will be exectued using the connection specified for the transformation. It will be executed on the target server and do whatever it is designed to do - there is no reference to target table. You may for example have a target table, `CITIES` and run a post SQL defined on it:

```
UPDATE MY_STATS_TABLE SET CNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CITIES) WHERE TBL = "CITY COUNT";
```

As a result, table `CITIES` will be loaded by the mapping, and table `MY_STATS_TABLE` will be updated via Post SQL.